# Verfiy collections inside collection in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

Source. [ [8,6,7] [8,7,8], [7,6,5] ]

Input [8,7,8]

Question : want to make sure source have the given input present or not.. if have then need yo return true else fase. In objective c or swift. Am new learner help to active this. Will really help full.

Instead of loop the operation any idea to manage. please guide me

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

```
let source: [[Int]] = [[8,6,7], [8,7,8], [7,6,5]]
let input: [Int] = [8,7,8]

print(source.contains(input)) // output: true or false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let source = [ [8,6,7], [8,7,8], [7,6,5] ]

let input = [8,7,8]

let isContainsInput = source.contains(where: { sourceItem in
    return sourceItem == input
})
```